# What's the advantage in using a helper class to define a constant?

Tags: c#

It was suggested to me that to define a constant I could have a helper class, like this, where you define all your colors / values

```
 public static class Styles
    {
         private static Color _backgroundColor = Color.FromHex("151515");
         public static Color BackgroundColor => _backgroundColor;
    }
```

Then, in xaml, you reference it in the header:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProjectAssembly.YourName;assembly=YourProjectAssembly.YourName"
```

And to use it:

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="{x:Static local:Styles.BackgroundColor}"/>
```

Can someone tell me what is the advantage of using a helper class like this when I could just declare a static class called Styles that has static variable with the value? Also is there another way that might be a better way to do this?

Comment: _a static class called Styles_ would be a Helper class.

Comment: You have all magic numbers in one reusable place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, helper class is not useful to have constants in it, but you can use a Helper class to load your constants from a config or resource file. using this method, whenever you want to change the styles, you don't need to rebuild your assembly, you just change it in the resource/config file. Now you can use your own Styles class to define the constants

```
    public static class Helper
    {
         public static Color GetColor()
         {
               var hexValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["colorHex"];
               private static Color _backgroundColor = Color.FromHex(hexValue);
               return _backgroundColor;
         }
    }
```

and config file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="colorHex" value="151515"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```